# Event LostFocus making datagridcell return previously entered value

Tags: c#, datagridview, event-handling

I have the following code:

```
if (GridSellProducts.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1 && e.Control is TextBox)
{
     TextBox textBox = e.Control as TextBox;
     textBox.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(QuantityFieldValidate);
     textBox.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(QuantityFieldValidate);
     textBox.LostFocus -= new EventHandler(QuantityCellLeave);
     textBox.LostFocus += new EventHandler(QuantityCellLeave);
}
```

and

```
private void QuantityCellLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // calculate total value
     quantity = Convert.ToDecimal(GridSellProducts.Rows[GridSellProducts.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells["Qnty"].Value);
}
```

The problem is that when I run the code for the first time and I enter a quantity in the Qnty field, the decimal `quantity` returns 0 no matter what number I enter e.g. 18. When I click back to the cell to enter another number say 23, decimal now returns number 18. 
Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to consume a different event; [`CellEndEdit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellendedit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex != qntyColumnIndex) { return; }

    quantity = Convert.ToDecimal(
        GridSellProducts.Rows[e.RowIndex]
                        .Cells["Qnty"].Value);

}
```

where `qntyColumnIndex` is the index of that column.

Comment: @KinyanjuiKamau, I'm glad I could be of assistance!